# Missing jar in Glassfish 3.1?

Tags: java, glassfish

Since migrating to Glassfish 3.1, my project cant source: `com.sun.xml.rpc.client.StubPropertyConstants;`. Glassfish 2.1 found this class under: webservices-rt.jar.

Does Glassfish 3.1 bundle with this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain as to why - although, adding the JAXWS-2.1 libraries to my project by right clicking `Libraries` and selected `Add Library` fixed this issue. I also opened my `jdk/jre/libs` dir and added an endorsed folder with `webservices-api.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need the [`jaxrpc-impl.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.rpc/jaxrpc-impl/1.1.3_01)

Answer (score 0):

No, the class is in GlassFish 3.1  modules/webservices-osgi.jar

But you might be hitting OSGi class loading isolation, which is a good thing...

Comment: what do you mean by _OSGI class loading isolation_ ?

Comment: This package would need to be in the list of exported packages from this bundle...Just checked and it is, so it should be visible...